# Vue.js using POST error(Sysntax but not find out)

Tags: vue.js

Thank you for reading this question.

I got a syntax error, but I can't find where.

I am using Vue.js & bootstrap, I am working on shopping cart functionality. In order for endpoints to work you need to pass a special authentication header:

Authorization: kazuhisa.noguchi.ghsd75@gmail.com

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
import MainPage from './components/MainPage.vue'
import HelpPage from './components/HelpPage.vue'
import ProductPage from './components/ProductPage.vue'
import CategoryPage from './components/CategoryPage.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
      path: '/',
      component: MainPage
    },
    {
      path: '/help',
      component: HelpPage
    },
    {
      path: '/products/:productId',
      component: ProductPage
    },
    {
      path: '/categories/:categoryAlias',
      component: CategoryPage
    }
  ],
  mode: 'history'
})

axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'azuhisa.noguchi.ghsd75@gmail.com';

axios.post("https://euas.person.ee/user/carts/").then(
  response => {
    new Vue({
      render: h => h(App),
      router: router,
      data: {
        cart: response.data,
        saveCard() {
          axios.put("https://euas.person.ee/user/carts/" +
            this.cart.id, this.cart)
        }
      }
    }).$mount('#app')
  }
};
```

All my best,

Comment: Syntax Error: SyntaxError: /Users/kazuhisanoguchi/Desktop/ecec/src/main.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (53:0)

  51 |     }).$mount('#app')
  52 |   }
> 53 | };
     | ^
  54 |


 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://10.11.0.49:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

Comment: I don't think you're closing your `.then` correctly. Try swapping the last `}` with a `)`